# Create custom namespace in phpunit test for MediaWiki extension

Tags: namespaces, phpunit, mediawiki-extensions

In phpunit tests for a MediaWiki extension, I am having trouble creating a custom namespace:

```
class NameSpaceTestCase extends \MediaWikiTestCase {
  public function testCustomNameSpace() {
    $ns = 4000;
    $this->setMwGlobals( [
      "wgExtraNamespaces[$ns]" => 'custom_namespace'
    ] );
    // global $wgExtraNamespaces;
    // $wgExtraNamespaces[$ns] = 'custom_namespace';
    $this->insertPage( 'in custom namespace', 'This is a page in a custom namespace', $ns );
    $this->assertTrue( MWNamespace::exists( $ns ), "The name space with id $ns should exist!" );
  }
}
```

The assertion that the namespace exists (in the last line of code) fails.

When I uncomment the currently commented lines (and comment the call to `setMwGlobals` instead) it still fails.

How can I programmatically create a namespace in MediaWiki?

Comment: Adding `[...]` to the end of a variable name doesn't do anything useful. You'll want `$this->mergeMwGlobalArrayValue( 'wgExtraNamespaces', [ $ns => 'custom_namespace' ] )`

Comment: Probably the namespaces have been cached by the time the test runs. You can call `MWNamespace::getCanonicalNamespaces( true )` to rebuild the cache.

Comment: Thanks @Tgr, that is the solution: Use `mergeMwGlobalArrayValue` followed by `MWNamespace::getCanonicalNamespaces( true )`. Do you want to add this as an answer? Then I can mark it as solved.

Comment: While the namespace is created all right, I am now facing an issue that `$this->insertPage( 'page in custom namespace', 'page content', $ns );` does not create a valid page: When I do `print_r ( $page, true )`, I get `[mPrefixedText:protected] => Special:Badtitle/NS4000:In custom namespace` and the unit tests fail. The extension code works fine with namespaces in production, so it must be something inherent to the unit tests.

Comment: More caching, probably? Try `$wgContLang->resetNamespaces()`.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick. All tests pass now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setMwGlobals` is not really useful for changing parts of globals; you can use `mergeMwGlobalArrayValue` instead, or use `stashMwGlobals` to make the test automatically restore the old value, then change it by hand. Plus you must make sure the old value is not stored anywhere - namespaces are looked up early in the request initialization lifecycle, and they include various things that are not that cheap (like running hooks for getting dynamically defined namespaces, and fetching translations) so tend to be cached. Unfortunately there isn't really any way to check that short of trying and the looking through the call tree and seeing where the value comes from. (MediaWiki is slowly moving towards a dependency injection based architecture where tests have more control over the state of the application, but is not quite there yet.)

Specifically, you can do something like

```
class NameSpaceTestCase extends \MediaWikiTestCase {
  public function testCustomNameSpace() {
    global $wgContLang;
    $ns = 4000;
    $this->mergeMwGlobalArrayValue( 'wgExtraNamespaces', [
      $ns => 'custom_namespace',
    ] );
    MWNamespace::getCanonicalNamespaces( true ); // break namespace cache
    $wgContLang->resetNamespaces(); // break namespace localization cache
    $this->insertPage( 'in custom namespace', 'This is a page in a custom namespace', $ns );
    $this->assertTrue( MWNamespace::exists( $ns ), "The name space with id $ns should exist!" );
  }
}
```